# Android ListView Replycating its values

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete my database child while **LongItemClick** using the following code. Remove procedure is working fine. But when I try to long press its replicating the ListView again and again. I didn't added any code for that in my `setOnItemLongClickListener`. Why its happening like this. I couldn't able to find from where its happening.

```
 private void showList() {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String retrievedName = bundle.getString("Name");
    final String retrievedMonth = bundle.getString("Month");

    customerList = findViewById(R.id.customerlistView);
    progress = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_cust_load);

    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    customerArray.clear();
    customerList.invalidateViews();


    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(retrievedName);
    DatabaseReference NameRef = ref.child(retrievedMonth);

    NameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                final String name = postSnapshot.getKey();
                customerArray.add(name);
                customerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, customerArray));
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if(customerArray.size()==0){

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.w("name", "load:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

        }
    });    

customerList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            customerList.invalidateViews();

            final String selectedFromList =(customerList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            final String retrievedName = bundle.getString("Name");
            final String retrievedMonth = bundle.getString("Month");

            final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference retrieveStatus = ref.child(retrievedName).child(retrievedMonth).child(selectedFromList).child("status");

            retrieveStatus.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String status=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                    String ID= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();

                    DatabaseReference details_edit=ref.child(retrievedName).child(retrievedMonth).child(selectedFromList).child("status");

                    details_edit.setValue("Dropped");

                    DatabaseReference status_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(ID)
                            .child("Customer Status").child("Dropped").child(selectedFromList);

                    Map statusPost = new HashMap();
                    statusPost.put("name", selectedFromList);

                    status_db.setValue(statusPost);

                    if(!status.equals("Dropped")){

                        assert ID != null;
                        DatabaseReference remove = ref.child(ID).child("Customer Status")
                                .child(status).child(selectedFromList);

                        remove.removeValue();

                    }else {

                    }

                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Show the code that you use to populate the list with data.

Comment: Updated my question. Please check once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think the problem is this:

1) You use a Value Event to listen to the data (keep in mind that this listener is very active).

2) Then when you long click you update a certain value in the database.

3) Because the ValueEventListener is very active it will respond to the change, and re populate the list.

Okay this is my analysis according to your code.

**Possible Solution:**

Try to listen once when you populate data.

So instead of this in the (showList() method):

```
NameRef.addValueEvent......
```

use this:

```
NameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(.....)
```

Hope it helps fix the problem.

Comment: I will check and let you know